# Creating JSX files giving me an error while trying to import React

Tags: reactjs, jsx, eslint

I usually create js files so this is my first time creating jsx files. Is there some lint settings I need to change to prevent it from giving me errors?

I only have this written in the Header component:

````
```import React from "react";

const Header = () => {
    return (
        <h1>Header</h1>
    )
}

export default Header;
````

[image: error]

Comment: Is it a standard create react app? How did you create the project?

Comment: npx create-react-app ./

Answer (score 0):

You are using deprecated "babel-eslint". Try with "@babel/eslint-parser"

https://github.com/eslint/eslint-scope/issues/77#issuecomment-1133775347